# Date input never null

Tags: jquery, html, date, keyup

I have this code

```
$("#inputId").keyup(function(){
    alert($("#inputId").val());
});
```

I know this is fairly basic(I'm not exactly sure what to google), but I'd like to know why that alert is always a null string.

EDIT-

For some reason, this wasn't included.

What I meant was when I type in the field, the alert never shows anything- if this was imprecise, apologies, I meant the alert shows up, but it always shows a null string(so it should show what's in the date field after a key has lifted, but does not) . That's still happening with the fixed html below.

EDIT (follow up question)-

Cool, so I accepted one of the answers below. I'd like to make it so that regardless of what I type, the value comes up in the alert (not just when the entry is in the date format). How do I achieve this?

HTML CODE-

```
<div id = "container">
        <input type = "date" id = "inputId" class = "inputClass"><br /></input>
        <div id="deleteContainer"><span id="x">x</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you placed a value in there? Also is this code within a `document.ready` callback?  Do you have an element in your markup with `id=inputID`?

Comment: What HTML code are you using?

Comment: sorry- for some reason the whole thing didn't post

Comment: so the alert comes up, but shows a null string

Comment: what about your HTML? Can you show us the *relevant* parts?

Comment: Show a http://jsfiddle.net illustrating your problem. Because, I can now post you a jsfiddle that works with this code. Conclusion: that's not all your code or the code you have shown is somehow different than your real code.

Comment: do `alert($("#inputId"));` what shows?

Comment: We don't need HTML, but, is the decent way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cV5ZT/2/) to test this and if you use and input type date then it should work.

Also changed $('#inputId') into $(this) which saves an extra query and is faster.

```
$("#inputId").keyup(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});​
```

As you can see in the Fiddle using the keyup with a date field (in Chrome) won't return a value until the date is correct.

You can't change the behavior of the date field, but you have two options.

- Change it into an input type text field and add your own validation.
- Get the value when a user leaves the field (this is the 'blur' event in HTML or
  'change' event in jQuery) and if the date is valid you get the value.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cV5ZT/3/) that demonstrates the change event instead of a keyup event.

**Update** Changed the fiddle to use input date

Comment: With input type `date` too: http://jsfiddle.net/cV5ZT/1/, The problem is broken HTML.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Thanks I changed it into input type date. Saw the updated question later.

Comment: wait, but the alert shows, but it does not show the value in the date field

Comment: @praks5432 can't find the problem. For me, the new JSFiddle is fine!

Comment: @praks5432 I noticed the same and updated my answer just now.

Comment: so when you type things in, after every key you type, the thing you just typed shows up? i.e. 'type 'd'' - alert('d') comes up?

Comment: there you go! That's what I wanted - I'll accept this, but I want to know how to make it so that whatever I type the alert comes up with the value- do you know how?

Comment: @praks5432 You can't change the behavior of the date field, but you have two options. 1: Change it into an input type text field and add your own validation. 2: Get the value when a user leaves the field (this is the blur event or change event in jQuery) and if the date is valid you get the value.

Answer (score 2):

`input` are broken. Change

```
<input type = "date" id = "inputId" class = "inputClass"><br /></input>
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to

```
<input type = "date" id = "inputId" class = "inputClass">
```

Comment: If this is real HTML, BTW, that slash shouldn't be there.  It's only useful for XHTML (HTML 5 allows but ignores it), and it's actually invalid in HTML 4.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed, but, it is HTML 5 (because of input date), with is why I put the end of input tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have broken HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="inputId" class="inputClass"><br /></input>
```

should be:

```
<input type="date" id="inputId" class="inputClass" /><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="inputId" type="text"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#inputId").keyup(function() {
            console.log($("#inputId").val());
        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```